# Cannot install Foxit Reader add-ons on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, pdf, foxit-reader

I'm trying to install the JPEG2000/JBIG Decoder add-on for Foxit Reader version 3.0.1817 running on Windows Vista SP1 and the install goes on for a couple of seconds then an error pops up saying "Access Denied". Is there a way to get add-ons to install successfully in this configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens try installing them as administrator?  Right-click Foxit and select *Run as administrator*, install the addons, then exit and run it normally.

Comment: Thx so much, it worked like a charm. Thx again!